# Windows Symbol server

Tags: windows, dll, debug-symbols

I want to set up a connection to the Windows Symbol server in Visual Studio.

I have the following command:

```
symsrv*symsrv.dll*c:\localcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

What should the `c:\localcache` part be changed to?

Comment: c:\localcache is the location to you want the symbols to be cached to; I just use C:\Symbols.

Comment: Okay, so you can put them anywhere and when you are debugging, the debugger will use them from that location?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That setting is only appropriate if you use the environment variable.  I'm pretty sure from previous questions that you actually use Visual Studio.  The MSDN page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx).  Or press F1 when you've got the dialog up.

Comment: Hi Hans, in that case then, do i not need to set the option of where to d/l the symbols from if I am using VS, I simply select a local cache folder as described in the tutorial?  Thanks.