# Information not avaliable, symbols not loaded for mfcore.dll

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, symbols

Alright so I am getting this error:

```
<Information not available, no symbols loaded for mfcore.dll>
```

I have read and people said it isn't a problem with the code so I think it would be pointless to post my code as it is irreverent. Anyways I am just trying to use MFCreateMediaSession and end up getting that error in my IMFMediaSession variable.

I've seen that it was not able to find the symbols from the mfcore.pdb but I have checked my computer far and wide and can not seem to find any file of the sort.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Not familiar with that one. Is it generated by a program crash, compiler, resource conflict between two hamsters fighting over a wheel, or what?

Comment: I believe it is the compiler.

Comment: You can use the symbol server as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226012/windows-symbol-server).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this particular one seems to be a longstanding problem specific to `mfcore.dll` for both the x86 and x64 builds. The **Visual Studio 2017** 'Modules' window says that the symbols for `mfcore.pdb` are loaded, but the entry in the "Symbol File" column which normally shows the full path to the PDB file is blank. Right-clicking the "Symbol Load Information" gives you:

```
C:\Windows\System32\mfcore.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\WINDOWS\mfcore.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\WINDOWS\symbols\dll\mfcore.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\WINDOWS\dll\mfcore.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\symbols\mfcore.pdb\1dbac8124f0c746624116b7feef848f81\mfcore.pdb: PDB does not match image.
C:\symbols\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\mfcore.pdb\1dbac8124f0c746624116b7feef848f81\mfcore.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Symbols downloaded from symbol server.
C:\symbols\mfcore.pdb\1DBAC8124F0C746624116B7FEEF848F81\mfcore.pdb: PDB does not match image.
```

So it's saying the PDB signature doesn't match the binaries, and it still happens with each new Windows debug symbols release, up to the latest 10.15063.296. Note that this information popup tells you where the debugger is progressively searching, the unique ID value it's looking for, and what's going wrong.

It might be a mismatch in the "age" part of the PDB signature, which the often helpful [**chkmatch.exe**](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html) tool isn't able to coerce. In fact, using that tool in this case to apply the signature correction seems to make the situation worse than described above, because the debugger refuses to even load the patched PDB, which eventually results in re-downloading the one with the mismatch (thus overwriting your patched version, if you didn't move it out of the local symbol store).

See also the [dumpbin.exe /PDBPATH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44wx0fef.aspx) option at MSDN, [this blog post](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/does-that-pdb-file-match-the-binary) at wintellect, and the [symchk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560157(v=vs.85).aspx) utility from the [SDK Debugging Tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx).